# Maven error in eclipse (pom.xml) : Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I wanna make web project using the Maven to import automatically all libraries that I need, so I chose `"maven-archetype-webpp"`

after that I got this error on pom.xml file :

```
Description Resource Path Location Type Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. pom.xml /SpringTuto line 1 Maven Configuration Problem
```

**I've updated my Maven project but with no results !!**

POM.XML :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pre.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringTuto</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringTuto Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringTuto</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: i have already Maven installed on Eclipse

Comment: Solution : right Click on project --> Run --> Intall Maven

Comment: This solved the same problem occurring for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38113729/4955513

Answer (score 84):

You need just to follow those steps:

1. Right Click on your project: Run (As) -> Maven clean
2. Right Click on your project: Run (As) -> Maven install

After which, if the build fails when you do Maven Install, it means there is no web.xml file under WEB-INF or some problem associated with it.
it really works

Comment: What was happening and why does it solve the problem. Please explain in your answer. I guess maven was not installed, but let's be sure.

Comment: maven update worked for me

Answer (score 12):

Right click on project-> Maven->Click checked box 'Force Update'->Update

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was a failed import to eclipse.
I had to delete the project from eclipse (without deleting form the filesystem of course) and reimport it. After that the error was gone immediately.

Comment: Saved my day, thanks for the tip. In my case I transfer the project to a new PC and hell broke loose...

Answer (score 2):

just right click on your project, hover maven then click update project.. done!!

Comment: OP states "im updated my Maven project but with no results ". You say simply updating the project is the solution. Really?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse Neon, try this:

1) Add the maven plugin in the properties section of  the POM:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

2) Force update of project snapshot by right clicking on Project

Maven -> Update Project -> Select your Project -> Tick on the 'Force Update of Snapshots/Releases' option -> OK

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your project: Run (As) -> Maven clean
Right Click on your project: Run (As) -> Maven install

Answer (score 0):

**For Unix Users**

> find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;

Right-click your project and choose Update Dependencies

***For Windows***

- CD (change directory) to .m2\repository
- execute the command `for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i`
- Then right-click
  your project and choose Update Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In my case eclipse was using an old settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier solution for this issue which worked for me like a charm.

Just **select Your project**.

Right click and select **Properties**.

In Left sidebar list select **Java Build Path**.

in the **Order and Export** tab check (1) **JRE System Library**[your java Version] and (2) **Maven Dependencies** ( which is initially unchecked ).

Then click **apply and close** Button.

just **update your project** ( automatically updates when hit apply and close ) and the Error is gone.