# Issues with building web application with Spring and Eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

Please I need help with resolving an issue with Spring and Eclipse. I have tried solving some other issues but this one is strange and I could not resolve it.

I am trying to build a web application using Spring and Eclipse but it showing an error on the pom.xml file. I have attached the pom.xml file.

> Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.18.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 
>    was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or 
>    updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.18.1 
>    from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/
>    plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.18.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.18.1.pom"

[The attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhn0h.jpg)

This is the full content of my pom;

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.userFront</groupId>
<artifactId>userFront</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>UserFront</name>
<description>User Frontend for Online Banking Project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-compiler-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [3.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Some of your pom is missing. Please copy/paste the content in your question or with pastebin.org ;)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project. Select Maven==> Update Project ==> Select (Enable check box) Force Update of Snapshots/Release.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to follow those steps:

Right Click on your project: Run (As) -> Maven clean

Right Click on your project: Run (As) -> Maven install

Same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447590/maven-error-in-eclipse-pom-xml-failure-to-transfer-org-apache-maven-plugins/33762105#33762105)